# Retraction, inclusion and homotopy

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a manifold, $S$ a submanifold of $M$, $r : M\rightarrow S$ the retraction map and $i : S \rightarrow M$ the inclusion map.

I know that the restriction $r_{|S}$ is equal to $id_S$, the identity map of $S$ in $S$.

Can I say that $r\circ i \sim_{\infty} id_S$, where $\sim_{\infty}$ is the homotopical equivalence?

I thought of this because $r\circ i$ can work as the restriction of $r$ over $S$ and the fact that $r_{|S} = id_S$ implies that $r_{|S} \sim_{\infty} id_S$ with a trivial homotopy.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. You have $r \circ i = id_S$ which is much stronger than $\sim_\infty$.

Comment: But how do I know for sure that $r \circ i = id_S$? $r$ being a retraction, I only know that  $i \circ r = id_M$ (by definition)

Comment: $i \circ r$ is not $= id_M$ unless $S = M$. But you certainly have $r \circ i = r \mid_S = id_S ((r \circ i)(x) = r(i(x)) = r(x) = x$ since $x \in S$).

Comment: Perhaps you've read the definition wrong. To say that $r : M \to S$ is a retraction means, *by definition*, that $r \circ i = \text{id}_S$. Not $i \circ r = \text{id}_M$. In fact if you think about the equation $i \circ r = \text{id}_M$, it implies that the inclusion map $i : S \to M$ is surjective, which is absurd if $S$ is a proper subset of $M$.

Comment: Yes, I've checked the definition and it's $i \circ r \sim_{\infty} id_M$

Comment: No. This would  mean that $M$ and $S$ are always homotopy equivalent. Let $M = S^1 \times S^1$ be the torus and $S = S^1 \times \{p\}$. This is a submanifold of $M$ and the map $r(x,y)  = (x,p)$ is a retraction. But definitely $M$ and $S$ are not homotopy equivalent.